# C Program : Display a Partially filled Array

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point

I need some help displaying a float array that's partially filled. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here's what I have.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE 20


int main()
{
    float score[SIZE];
    float GPA, sum, avg;
    int count, ctr, num_of_entries;
    sum = 0;


for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    printf("Enter a GPA. -1 to stop the data entry:  ");
    scanf("%f", &GPA);
        if (GPA == -1)
            break;
    score[count] = GPA;
}
printf("Number of GPAs entered = %d", count);
num_of_entries = count;
printf("\n\nContent of the Array:\n=========================\n");

for (ctr = 0; ctr <= num_of_entries; ctr++);
{
    printf("%.2f \n", score[ctr]);
}

    _getch();         
return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to display the entered GPA values as float variables with 2 decimal places. The printed result is a very large negative number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are two errors on line 26. Can you find them?

Comment: `ctr <= num_of_entries` --> `ctr < num_of_entries` , `ctr++);` --> `ctr++)`

Comment: I would guess that your array doesn't get intialized properly. When you declare the array, try this instead: `float score[SIZE] = { 0 };`. This will initialize every member to 0.0f.

Comment: Initializing all indexes to 0 results in the array being displayed as just 0, so that's a start

Comment: when you are debugging, can you see a valid value coming out with `scanf("%f", &GPA);`?. It looks like the line `score[count] = GPA;` never gets hit, which means that the `break;` statement is hit on the first run. Also, it is a bad idea to compare a float like this `if (GPA == -1)`. See [this post](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Howto_compare_floating_point_numbers_in_the_C_programming_language)

Comment: In addition, you should initialize `float GPA = 0`. In fact, initializing variables when you declare them is always a good idea. [Read this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223862/how-important-is-to-initialize-a-variable)

Comment: The 'printf("Number of GPAs entered = %d", count);' displays the correct amount of cycles, so I don't think the break is being executed until -1 is input. The prompt continues to run until -1 is entered as well.

I initialized the rest of the variables as well, nothing changed. As far as the comparing of the float value, we haven't been taught that there's an issue with == comparisons, so I'm not sure that I should implement that. 

I appreciate your help this far though, truly

Comment: I figured it out, haha, I had a semicolon at the end of the line with the for loop. Good to know for the future about initialization and float accuracy for comparisons, thank you all!

Comment: @Nik `if (GPA == -1)` is fine - comparing to a value that is exactly representably as a `float` is not an issue.  The referenced link to compare is weak.  Its approach is not valid for large nor small FP values.  It takes the "floating" out of floating point.